# TableView, incompatible types for defining custom editing behaviour

Tags: type-conversion, tableview, javafx-8

(I am kind of stepping in the dark here, so excuse me if what I wrote isnt clear enough and just ask for additional information.)

I have a DataModel with I use as data for my TableView. DataModel contains String and Integer data for name, surname, age and tel. number.

```
public class DataModel {
   private SimpleStringProperty sName;
   private SimpleStringProperty sSurname;
   private SimpleIntegerProperty iAge;
   private SimpleIntegerProperty iPhoneNumber;

   public DataModel(String sName, String sSurname, int iAge, int iPhoneNumber) {
      this.sName = new SimpleStringProperty(sName);
      this.sSurname = new SimpleStringProperty(sSurname);
      this.iAge = new SimpleIntegerProperty(iAge);
      this.iPhoneNumber = new SimpleIntegerProperty(iPhoneNumber);
   }
//...getters and setters..
```

When I do custom cell editing events with EditingCell class(as explained here [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/user-interface-tutorial/table-view.htm)
) It works for SimpleStringProperties of DataModel and its not working for SimpleIntegerValues:

```
    Callback<TableColumn<DataModel, String>, TableCell<DataModel, String>> cellFactory = (TableColumn<DataModel, String> p) -> new EditingCell();

    surnameColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel>forTableColumn());
    surnameColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory);
    surnameColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<DataModel, String> event) -> {
        ((DataModel) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setsSurname(event.getNewValue());
    });
    ageColumn.setCellFactory(TextFieldTableCell.<DataModel, Integer>forTableColumn(new IntegerStringConverter()));
X   ageColumn.setCellFactory(cellFactory); //dodajemy custom editing event
XX  ageColumn.setOnEditCommit((CellEditEvent<DataModel, Integer> event) -> {
    ((DataModel) event.getTableView().getItems(). get(event.getTablePosition().getRow())).  setiAge(event.getNewValue());
    });
```

X is where compiler send me error:

```
The method setCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<DataModel,Integer>,TableCell<DataModel,Integer>>) in the type TableColumn<DataModel,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (Callback<TableColumn<DataModel,String>,TableCell<DataModel,String>>)
```

XX is place where compiler send me error:

```
The method setOnEditCommit(EventHandler<TableColumn.CellEditEvent<DataModel,Integer>>) in the type TableColumn<DataModel,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments ((CellEditEvent<DataModel, Integer> event) -> {})
```

There seems to be not much materials over the internet about using TableView. Beside these errors above, I wonder is it best generaly to use only SimpleStringProperties for Data Class and later just do some conversions?

EDIT: 
Here is EditingCell implementation.

```
package application;

import javafx.beans.value.ObservableValue;
import javafx.scene.control.TableCell;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;

//Klasa ta pozwala na definiowania zachowania komórek, które edytuje użytkownik
public class EditingCell extends TableCell<DataModel, String>{ 
private TextField textField;

public EditingCell() {
}

@Override
public void startEdit() {
    if (!isEmpty()) {
        super.startEdit();
        createTextField();
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(textField);
        textField.selectAll();
    }
}

@Override
public void cancelEdit() {
    super.cancelEdit();

    setText((String) getItem());
    setGraphic(null);
}

@Override
public void updateItem(String item, boolean empty) {
    super.updateItem(item, empty);

    if (empty) {
        setText(null);
        setGraphic(null);
    } else {
        if (isEditing()) {
            if (textField != null) {
                textField.setText(getString());
            }
            setText(null);
            setGraphic(textField);
        } else {
            setText(getString());
            setGraphic(null);
        }
    }
}

private void createTextField() {
    textField = new TextField(getString());
    textField.setMinWidth(this.getWidth() - this.getGraphicTextGap()* 2);
    textField.focusedProperty().addListener(
        (ObservableValue<? extends Boolean> arg0, 
        Boolean arg1, Boolean arg2) -> {
            if (!arg2) {
                commitEdit(textField.getText());
            }
    });
}

private String getString() {
    return getItem() == null ? "" : getItem().toString();
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the second error (`ageColumn.setOnEditCommit(...)`) is only showing up in your IDE as a result of the first error. When I try that on its own it works fine for me.

I can't recreate the first error because you didn't post the `EditingCell`; however you clearly have mismatched types here. `TableColumn<S,T>` defines a [`setCellFactory(Callback<TableColumn<S,T>, TableCell<S,T>>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/scene/control/TableColumn.html#setCellFactory-javafx.util.Callback-) method. For your `ageColumn`, the types are `S=DataModel` and `T=Integer`, so you need to pass it a `Callback<TableColumn<DataModel, Integer>, TableCell<DataModel, Integer>>`, which is not the type you declared for your `cellFactory`. I assume `EditingCell` is a subclass of `TableCell<String>` (else the declaration of `cellFactory` would not compile). You need to create another class (say `AgeCell`) that is a subclass of `TableCell<Integer>` and then do

```
Callback<TableColumn<DataModel, Integer>, TableCell<DataModel, Integer>> ageCellFactory = (TableColumn<DataModel, Integer> col) -> new AgeCell();
```

Depending on how your `EditingCell` is implemented, and how much you need to know about the type of object in your cell, you might be able to make it a generic class:

```
public class EditingCell<T> extends TableCell<DataModel, T> {
    @Override
    public void updateItem(T item, boolean empty) {
        // ...
    }

    // ...
}
```

Then you can do things like

```
surnameCol.setCellFactory(column -> new EditingCell<String>());
ageCol.setCellFactory(column -> new EditingCell<Integer>());
```

Without knowing your `EditingCell` implementation, it is hard to know whether or not this is a viable option. The `EditingCell` would probably need to be passed a `StringConverter<T>` to convert values from the `TextField` to the value to give to the `DataModel`, and to convert from data model values to values to be displayed.

> I wonder is it best generaly to use only SimpleStringProperties for
>   Data Class and later just do some conversions?

Definitely not. Everything (almost) in JavaFX is set up to be generic, so you should take advantage of that and use the appropriate types in your data model.

Comment: Creating another class helped however I was expecting some easier solution, because If i have lets say: Integer, String, Boolean, Char and Double values in Data Class then I will need 5 Cell classes... thats why I was thinking maybe it would be best to have only String values and do conversions. Still I think it may be better in this situation

Comment: I have pasted the implementationof EditingCell class